# wrong fs type, bad options, bad superblock

Tags: linux, terminal, mount, disk, partition

I am getting this error:

```
mount: /mnt/dev/sda3: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

And this:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

But still no good.

I typed

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and got this output

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 204802047 204083200  97.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       204802110 512002047 307199938 146.5G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       512002048 976771071 464769024 221.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       204802112 339970047 135167936  64.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       339972096 355971071  15998976   7.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       355973120 512002047 156028928  74.4G 83 Linux

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I have to access /dev/sda4 , sda5. I can access it through File Manager but not through Terminal.

I'm Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mount sda3 as it is extended partition. Try to mount logical partitions created in sda3: sda5 or sda7. sda6 is swap partition so it cannot be mounted.

Comment: Agreed. I'm trying on sda5 or sda4. No success.

Comment: I also tried to using mount -a instead of mount -i. It did not gave me any error but didn't worked either.